# Laravel App logs out each time i visit a route

Tags: laravel, authentication

There is a problem with my Laravel App, whenever a user logs in it logs the user in.

At this point if i return a view it still stays logged in but if i redirect to any route at all (protected or not), it automatically logs the user out and redirects to login page.

Comment: Sounds like the session is being lost, or you don't have the session middleware on the route. Check `app/Http/Kernel.php` for the middleware, and check that your session driver is properly configured.

Answer (score 0):

You session and auth guard is not configured properly please check this and also you can use laravel auth package for login/register

Comment: Thanks. Please how can i be sure they are configured properly?

Answer (score 0):

So i resolved it following this :

SOLUTION:

1. Go to your .env file and change SESSION_DRIVER=file to SESSION_DRIVER=database.
2. Next you will need to create a session migration: php artisan session:table.
3. Now composer dump-autoload for good practice.
4. Finally migrate (php artisan migrate).